# Change SQL User to Trusted User Using Manifest File and C#

Tags: c#, database-connection

I inherited a project that uses SQL authentication and a manifest file to connect to the database.  We are using SQL Server.

This is the manifest file:

```
<database>
   <server>server1\dbname</server>
   <catalog>CatName</catalog>
   <username>sysuser</username>
   <password>ksdjf290384</password>

</database>
```

This is the code to it as a connection:

```
        this.Manifest = new XmlDocument();
        this.Manifest.Load(manifestPath);
        XmlNode rootNode = this.Manifest.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/manifest");
        XmlNode dbNode = rootNode.SelectSingleNode("database");
        this.Connector = new SqlConnector(string.Format(CONNECTION_STRING_TEMPLATE, dbNode.SelectSingleNode("server").InnerText, dbNode.SelectSingleNode("catalog").InnerText, dbNode.SelectSingleNode("username").InnerText, dbNode.SelectSingleNode("password").InnerText));
```

I need to change this to Windows Authentication.  I can't figure out how to change the manifest file and the code to work.

I have tried eliminating the username and password from the manifest file and connector.  I've tried to shoehorn Trusted_Connection in but nothing seems to work.

I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas on this.

Comment: What is the database server? Is it SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that is was never designed to support Windows Authentication. You can invent a new property, for example `integratedsecurity`, or just assume it is using Windows Authentication if the `username` is missing or empty.

Manifest file:

```
<database>
   <server>server1\dbname</server>
   <catalog>CatName</catalog>
   <integratedsecurity>SSPI</integratedsecurity>
</database>
```

This is the code to connect:

```
this.Manifest = new XmlDocument();
this.Manifest.Load(manifestPath);
XmlNode rootNode = this.Manifest.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/manifest");
XmlNode dbNode = rootNode.SelectSingleNode("database");
XmlNode userNameNode = rootNode.SelectSingleNode("username");
XmlNode passwordNode = rootNode.SelectSingleNode("password");
XmlNode integratedSecurityNode = rootNode.SelectSingleNode("integratedsecurity");
if (integratedSecurityNode != null || userNameNode == null 
|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(userNameNode))
{
    this.Connector = new SqlConnector(string.Format("Server={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=SSPI;", dbNode.SelectSingleNode("server").InnerText, dbNode.SelectSingleNode("catalog").InnerText);
}
else 
{
    this.Connector = new SqlConnector(string.Format(CONNECTION_STRING_TEMPLATE, dbNode.SelectSingleNode("server").InnerText, dbNode.SelectSingleNode("catalog").InnerText, userNameNode.InnerText, dbNode.SelectSingleNode("password").InnerText));
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Did the trick!  I had to change | string.IsNullOrEmpty(userNameNode)) to  string.IsNullOrEmpty(userNameNode.ToString())) but otherwise good to go :)

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work:

Menifast file:

```
<database>
   <server>server1\dbname</server>
   <catalog>CatName</catalog>
</database>
```

The code:

```
        this.Manifest = new XmlDocument();
        this.Manifest.Load(manifestPath);
        XmlNode rootNode = this.Manifest.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("database");
        XmlNode userNameNode = rootNode.SelectSingleNode("username");
        XmlNode passwordNode = rootNode.SelectSingleNode("password");

        if (userNameNode != null && passwordNode != null)
        {

            this.Connector = new SqlConnector(string.Format(CONNECTION_STRING_TEMPLATE, rootNode.SelectSingleNode("server").InnerText, rootNode.SelectSingleNode("catalog").InnerText, userNameNode.InnerText, passwordNode.InnerText));

        }
        else 
        {
            //Windows authentication
            this.Connector = new SqlConnector(string.Format("Server={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=SSPI;", rootNode.SelectSingleNode("server").InnerText, rootNode.SelectSingleNode("catalog").InnerText);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer +1   I awarded my bounty to the the other guy whose solution was posted first.  This looks like it would work, too :)